# Dynamic table with input field jquery click edit button, enable field

Tags: jquery

I am writing a laravel application where I have a table of disabled input fields with `edit` button on each. I want to click the edit button to enable the input field on which that button was clicked.

This is my view.blade.php

```
  @foreach($products as $product)
                <tbody>     
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="1" class="form-control" 
                        value="{{ $product->quantity }}" disabled="" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="1" class="form-control" 
                        value="{{ $product->description }}" disabled="" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="1" class="form-control" 
                        value="{{ $product->selling_price }}" disabled="" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <button id="edit" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                        Edit</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
         @endforeach
```

This is my jquery script

```
       $('#edit').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: id should be unique for each element .take care about that . instead of id use class name  $(this).parent("tr").find('input').prop('disabled', false);

Comment: This did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically generated HTML, the jQuery click binding for the edit needs to be different. And for better clarity, its better to use a class name instead of an ID for the edit button, since same class names can be reused and ID should be unique to an element.

Your jQuery code should be something like

```
$('.container').on('click', '.edit', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

here, your container element should already be available and the content within will be dynamically rendered. This will auto bind the click event to all class name with value **edit**

Comment: If I do that, it will enable all the input fields.  I am making a foreach loop using php.

Comment: @nana You will still have the disabled attribute when dynamically generating your markup. 

I have created a sample fiddle. Take a look and see if this is what you were looking for.
[link]https://jsfiddle.net/kvrahul66/gqvbtp69/4/

**Note:** Please change the name attributes of your input fields. They all have the same name as of now.